# Adding LED feedback to a source selection switch

Tags: led, switches, audio

I am working on creating an amplifier with multiple input sources. I have implemented a 3P4T rotary switch to be able to select the audio source among 4 different ones : RCA, Phono, and 2 digital sources coming out of the same DAC. There is a multiplexer above the DAC to select which digital source to send to the DAC. Here is a functionnal drawing of my setup :

[image: Functionnal drawing]

As you can see, the 3 poles of the switch are used for : 1. Multiplexer source selection, 2. Left channel, 3. Right channel.

Now I need to be able to add 4 LEDs, to display visually which source is activated.

Obviously, the easy solution would be to use a 4P4T switch instead, and use the 4th pole to handle the LEDs, but here comes the constraint : **I need the switch to be able to be soldered directly on the board.** However, all 4P4T switches I have seen have at least 2 decks [such as this one](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1786562831.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.fe946defvOQ6fd&algo_pvid=ac35ef17-934a-4f8e-a366-2ace98cbfbe8&algo_exp_id=ac35ef17-934a-4f8e-a366-2ace98cbfbe8-22&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2267403570751%22%7D), which seems to mean it's impossible to just solder it on a board, compared to a 3P4T which can, thanks to their 15 THT pins [like those](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32840329605.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.3bf36defujvev4&algo_pvid=5b6ac476-e979-46e2-9d18-3e9a9b69cbb4&algo_exp_id=5b6ac476-e979-46e2-9d18-3e9a9b69cbb4-1&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2265492358877%22%7D)

Hence, my question is the following : **how would it be possible to install LEDs on the output of a 3P4T when all the pins are already used ?** Could I use one of the poles to perform two actions ? Or do you have another solution in mind ? I've been searching for one all day and can't seem to have a lead. Maybe there's an easy solution I have missed by being to stubborn on one idea, I don't know.

I'd like to avoid having to use a µcontroller, and I need components which can be soldered directly to the board... Else you understand that I would have jumped on a 4P4T.

Hopefully I was clear enough. If not, don't hesitate to ask for more information.
Big thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it (common on switch to +5V):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNOmbJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your LEDs are different colors you may wish to use individual resistors rather than R1 to match brightness between the LEDs.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's exactly what I needed ! I knew it wasn't that hard and the solution was right there. Thanks again for taking the time to have a look into it !